# JAXB unmarshaller returns default values for fields

Tags: soap, jaxb, java-11

I am trying to write a SOAP client and one of its tasks is to unmarshall a SOAP response. But the problem is that whenever I try to unmarshal the response, I am getting null values only.

Here's a sample soap response

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:CreateOrderResponse xmlns:ns2="https://myns.com">
            <ns2:OrderID>100100</ns2:OrderID>
        </ns2:CreateOrderResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and this is the POJO that the body of the soap message is supposed to be unmarshalled to

```java
package per.me.soapclient.response

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import lombok.Getter;

@XmlRootElement(name = "CreateOrderResponse", namespace = "https://myns.com")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"orderID"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
public class GetOrderResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "OrderID", namespace = "https://myns.com")
    public Long orderID;

}
```

This is the unmarshalling logic

```java
String soapXML = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
                                "    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>\n" +
                                "    <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                                "        <ns2:CreateOrderResponse xmlns:ns2=\"https://myns.com\">\n" +
                                "            <ns2:OrderID>100100</ns2:OrderID>\n" +
                                "        </ns2:CreateOrderResponse>\n" +
                                "    </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                                "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"

try {
      final MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
      final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateOrderResponse.class);
      final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      try(ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapXML.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        final SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), bais);
        CreateOrderResponse response = unmarshaller.unmarshall(soapMessage.getSOAPBody(), CreateOrderResponse.class).getValue();

        Assertions.assertEquals(100100L, response.getOrderID());
      }
    } catch (SOAPException | JAXBException | IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

The assertion fails with the following message

```
expected: <100100> but was: <null>
Expected :100100
Actual   :null
```

Just in case, here's my `package-info.java`

```java
@XmlSchema(namespace = "https://myns.com", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package per.me.soapclient.response;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm stuck and I can't really think of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very silly of me. The element to be passed to the unmarshaller is not the soap body but the first child element under the `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` tag.

so I just needed to do something like

```java
CreateOrderResponse response = unmarshaller.unmarshal(soapMessage.getSOAPBody().getChildElements().next(), CreateOrderResponse.class).getValue();
```